# Express router not catching requests, while static serving does work

Tags: express, vue.js

I'm trying to combine JSON API endpoint serving with the standard project created by [vue-cli webpack template](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack). Trying to hook `/api` endpoint to my JSON API router.

This doesn't work (/api requests return 404):

```
api = express.Router()
api.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  res.send('write.io API server')
})
app.use('/api', api)
```

while connecting a static route to the same path works

```
app.use('/api', express.static('./static')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your first block of code based on what you show.  Your one route should respond to `/api`.  If it's not responding to taht, then you must have more going on then you show here.

Comment: Yeah, I have a large file generated by the template. Some part of that must be making the router not work, but I don't understand why it would do that, but keep the static route working.

Comment: Code here: http://pastebin.com/kZPN4BF8

Comment: That pastebin doesn't seem to have the code for `api.js` where the router is defined.

Comment: @jfriend00 yeah, for the purpose of testing I used a new empty router as posted in the question.

Comment: Well a simple router like you show works just fine.  So, there's more to the problem than that.  I'm not sure what else is involved in your environment that causes the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134616/discussion-between-ripper234-and-jfriend00).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `connect-history-api-fallback`.

> This tiny middleware addresses some of the issues. Specifically, it
>   will change the requested location to the index you specify (default
>   being /index.html) whenever there is a request which fulfills the
>   following criteria: